# Mudar a orientação dentro de um botão com icone

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Sou novo com Android Studio e estou tentando fazer um botão com ícone em cima, fiz o layout no figma segue a baixo.

[image: Layout feito no figma]

Entretanto no Android Studio o ícone fica ao lado do texto segue abaixo a imagem do problema.

[image: Botao com o icone errado]

Codigo xml do botao.

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCategoriaProdutos"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/lsenac"
        android:backgroundTintMode="add"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_iconcategoriaprodutos"
        android:text="CATEGORIA PRODUTOS">

    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -2):

Resolvido segue o codigo xml para o posicionamento do icone.

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCategoriaProdutos"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/lsenac"
        android:text="CATEGORIA PRODUTOS"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_iconcategoriaprodutos"
        app:iconGravity="textTop"
        app:iconPadding="35dp"
        app:iconSize="40dp">

    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Seria bom deixar claro qual propriedade resolve o problema. Acredito que seja a `app:iconGravity="textTop"`